# Increment and decrement with pointer arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My teacher provided me with this code and it returns **31,40**, but I am unable to figure out why. What is the reason for it returning what it does?

```
void main() {
    int *ptr;
    int arr[5] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    ptr = &arr[3];
    cout << ++*ptr-- << ", " << *ptr;
}
```

Comment: It is UB as there is no sequence point between the last `*ptr` and the first `ptr--`.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main()`; anyone trying to teach C++ should know that. Your title mentions "pointer arrays", but there is no "pointer array' in your program; there's an array, and there's a pointer.

Comment: @Jarod42: `<<` is overloaded; it's a function call, not a built-in operator. I *think* that provides enough sequence points to make the behavior well defined -- but it's butt-ugly code that should be re-written.

Comment: @KeithThompson: No, there's no call to `<<` between `++` and `--`, so no sequencing.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I think you're right. (If it were my code, I'd spend my time rewriting it rather than figuring out whether its behavior is defined.)

Comment: @KeithThompson This function is from an exam. Sorry for "pointer arrays" stuff...my english sucks.

Comment: I get a different result with GCC 4.9.2 on Arch Linux:  I get "41, 40".  It's odd that you got "31,30" (especially because you got no space after the comma).  Did you actually run this?  What compiler?

Comment: @David Grayson Space is irrelevant. I've used Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't tell us the space is irrelevant. You should include the *exact* output in the question. If you aren't getting a space, that would indicate a serious problem somewhere.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `++*ptr--` is fine. The `++` and the `--` are not modifying the same thing (`--` on the pointer, `++` on the pointee). The problem is `ptr--` and `*ptr`.

Comment: @Namfuak She's the one that makes the test, correct them and shows us _the bad grades_. Thug life.

Comment: @T.C. I think that too. Maybe that's the answer?

Comment: It looks to me like it should be either "41, 40" or "41, 30" but you said you got 31 for the first number?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Actually, in MinGW it shows me **41, 30**. Weird.

Comment: Maybe the question was to point out the bugs in the code.. before you bash the teacher..

Comment: `void main()` means that, strictly speaking, the program is ill-formed. The lack of `#include <iostream>` means that the name `cout` and the `<<` operator aren't visible, so this code won't even compile. C++ compilers can still accept ill-formed programs, and the missing `#include` could simply mean that this is a code fragment, not a complete program.

Answer (score 5):

```
cout << ++*ptr-- << ", " << *ptr;
```

is

```
operator <<(cout.operator <<(++*ptr--), ", ").operator <<(*ptr);
```

The problem can be reduced to:

```
f(f(ptr--), ptr)
```

whereas order of evaluation between `f(ptr--)` and `ptr` is unspecified (and more specificaly between `ptr--` and `ptr`).

So you got undefined behavior for the given code.

Comment: It is `operator<<(cout.operator<<(++*ptr--), ", ").operator<<(*ptr);`. The first and third are members. The second is a nonmember.

Comment: @T.C.: fixed, thanks (even if it doesn't change the answer)

Comment: @KennyOstrom Nope, it's undefined.

Comment: okay, unspecified does get promoted to ub, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard states

> **Section 1.9/15 [intro.execution]** : Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual
>   expressions are unsequenced. (...) If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the
>   same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same
>   scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

`++*ptr--` and `*ptr` are unsequenced subexpressions of the same expression using the same object: nothing guarantees that they are evaluated from left to right.  So according to the standard, this results in undefined behaviour.  Your result tend to show that your compiler chooses to evaluate first `*ptr` and then `++*ptr--`.

*Edit:*  `++*ptr--` is `++(*ptr--))`.  Here the operand of operator `++` also uses object `ptr` on which `--` does a side effect.  So this is undefined behaviour as well.  It appears that in your case, the compiler first evaluates `*ptr--` which results in 40 and a decremented `ptr`, and then applies `++` on the dereferenced decremented pointer (i.e. 30 incremented by 1).